# Spring Data Neo4J 4.0.0 : What is the right sequence of calls to lookup by property?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am doing a simple Camel Case lookup on a node in Neo4J 4.0.0.M1:

e.g.

```
UserRepository.findByUserId(String userId);
```

I can see in my log file that the correct Cypher query is generated:

```
match (u:User) where u.userId = {0} return u
```

and I can run this code in the Neo4J browser with the expected result of one node being returned.  I can also see the correct JSON getting generated

e.g.

```
21:53:39.819 [tomcat-http--37] INFO  o.n.o.session.request.DefaultRequest - POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"match (u:User) where u.userId = {0} return u","parameters":{"0":"145"},"resultDataContents":["graph"]}]}
```

and I can run this from PostMaster and get the expected result of one node being returned.

However, running this through code with a named Query in a `GraphRepository` returns every node that is currently, I believe, in the `Neo4JSession`.

Here is the UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

    @Query ("match (u:User) where u.userId = {0} return u")
    public List<User> findByUserId(String userId);

}
```

Running this code returns ever user I have ever created in Neo4J.

Note that I have changed the return type to a List because the expected behavior of one node being returned was not happening and I was getting a mapping exception.  Also note that there is a named query here because I wasn't sure if the problem might be with the Camel Case lookup vs. a named query.

This was also working correctly in Neo4J 3.3.x

Also, I have traced the problem to `Neo4JSession.query()` where a call is being made to  Neo4JSession.query which in turn does the following:

```
return getResponseHandler().loadAll(type, response);
```

This is returning all nodes in the MappingContext with the given class type.  It should, I believe, be calling `Neo4JSession.loadByProperty` which does the lookup on the node.

Is there a setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Query` returning undesired results has been fixed post the M1 release. Could you use a snapshot build to try this again?

http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if this was a bug or a new feature of 4.0.0 that required some additional config.